# How to remove paragraph marks in Aquamacs - Emacs

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

My aquamac shows the tags when I create a new paragraph or line break, I want to know how to remove these marks.

[image]

Comment: It appears this is some alternate newline character (not paragraph!). Could you check when you put point before it, to find out which character it is? `M-x describe-char`

Comment: Are you using whitespace-mode?  There are options in there to display the pilcrow (the backwards P you see) for paragraphs.  http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/whitespace-mode.html.  Try this in your .emacs file to see if it helps - (setq whitespace-display-mappings nil).  Either restart emacs or eval it.